# Q: Is it Possible If I have a Column that marks a Job's current Status/Progress to send a Weekly Email?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Rather than sending an email whenever an item is changed/created and the status is added/updated?

I have a list that has a list of jobs and a varying amount of variables that employees check off such as if it requires central notification or if it has  a large investment. The Job status is essentially split between three columns one marking it ready for work (Yes/No) one marking it complete (Yes/No) and then a approval of the completion marking it as Approved/Rejected/Requires Review. I'll outline the overall process below:

1. Group 2 Reviews the List and determines if a Job is Ready to be Worked.
2. Group 1 receives a email when the job is marked
   Ready for Work by Group 2.
3. Group 1 then completes the work and marks it complete and Group 2
      gets an email of the completion mark.
4. Group 2 is then required to review and mark the completed job as Approved/Rejected/Requires Review.
5. Once Group 2 marks it appropriately Group 1 is responsible for moving ahead with updating records or meeting with Group 2 on why it was Rejected or what portion of the task requires Review.

Now what I want is that rather than send the emails once every step is completed it sends a weekly "reminder" to both groups of what items (Job and Job ID) need to be done meaning they are somewhere in the steps I outlined above. (Group 1 notified that jobs x y z are workable and group 2 receiving emails that job x y z has been worked and needs approval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced this kind of requirement.
To achieve this, You need to *write the PowerShell script,* that loops all the list items and collect the items based on your requirement and use send email command to set the email.

Then attach that script in the *"Task Scheduler(Windows)"* and set it to run on every week.